# Generate ID for the grid of points from top-left corner down

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, point, vector-grid

I have a grid of points extracted from a raster. I need to give them a new ID value to be able to join values from it to another grid in rotated system of coordinates.The automatically generated ID goes from top-left to the right and I need it to be from top-left down. 
Something like this:

Current:

### 1   2   3   4

### 5   6   7   8

### 9 10 11 12

What is needed:

### 1  5  9

### 2  6  10

### 3  7  11

### 4  8  12

I have 122140 features so I'd rather not do it manually. I use QGIS 2.8.2 and ArcGIS 10.1. No programming skills for the time being.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools in QGIS or ArcGIS that allow custom grid progressions for labeling (ie choosing row-column vs column-row). This is sort of a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92464/ though no answer was found there and it sought a slightly different pattern. There's also some relevant comment discussion at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150081/

Comment: It's late, but I *think* you could do this with some XY coordinate calculation and Excel trickery because of the pattern you want. Calc the XY coordinates into separate fields, export table and open in Excel or other spreadsheet. Do a multi-field sort on X first and Y second (making sure you use ascending or descending order as needed). This should put the points in the order you want them numbered, and you can just use autofill on a new column to get sequential numbers, then join that back to your original points. Can't test now, but can try later or if it works can turn in to an answer.

Comment: Hey @ChrisW. Thanks for the reply. it looks like the Excel trickery might be a solution as well. I already solved the problem. Used Excel formula to make a sequence of number with the proper increment that matched my points, repeated that several times, and then simply copy-pasted it to column in attribute table in ArcGIS. Not most elegant solution but worked ;) thanks for taking the time to think of my problem!